No bean found for PubSubTemplate, spring boot 3, GCP PUB/SUB
I am trying to integrate GCP pub/sub with my existing Spring Boot application. I have the required dependencies in the build and provided the config to connect to GCP with subscription config and projectID in the application.yaml.
Yet, PubSubTemplate  is not getting initialized in the project.
Spring Boot Version: 3.2
Gradle settings:
dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE"
}

ext {
    set('springCloudGcpVersion', "5.1.2")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.1")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        //mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
    }
}

application.yaml
spring:
    cloud:
        gcp:
            credentials:
                location: classpath:/1045745-2d4cbe960a5b.json
            project-id: poc-pub-sub
        pubsub:
            enabled: true

Code:
@Configuration
public class Extractor {
@Autowired
  private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;
}

Runtime Error:
com.Extractor required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' in your configuration.

I suppose the bean needs to be autoconfigured by spring with a default implementation as per documentation. Is something missing here?

Try to create a Bean of type PubSubTemplate in the standard way, see if that helps. I'm not sure if this is THE solution, but I suspect it will help.

Remove the version from the spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub dependency. The proper version should be set through those imports. Generally those errors come from mixing incompatible versions.

@M.Deinum I get an error if I remove version: Could not resolve: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub

@CaptainChaos I have already tried it. I get dependent bean errors: Parameter 0 of method pubSubTemplate in com.PubSubConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate' that could not be found.

The issue got resolved after changing the dependency
from
dependencies {

    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE"
}

TO
dependencies {

 implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
}

